# jvmToolchain doesn't set compileDebugJavaWithJavac version (inconsistent JVM-target compatibility)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jvm

Upgrading to Kotlin 1.9.21 (from 1.8), compilation now fails with below error. Our project is a multi-module project, and this error is hit from the first module being compiled.

`Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (11) and 'kspDebugKotlin' (17).`

`build.gradle` below - I've read many, many of the threads and have all the things, to the point of being redundant (also, does jvmToolchain go into top block or android block? I just added to both).

#### build.gradle

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
        }
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle.kts

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(17)
}
android {
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
```

#### settings.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.7.0'
}
```

#### Additional notes/clues/questions

- For some reason works on my machine, but not on our build machines. Is there some additional configuration somewhere that doesn't match?
- Running build with `--info` flag, confirmed that it's running with JDK 17.
- Is it possible for a dependency to be triggering this? Seems like not, because the error message is that it's related to the gradle task.
- Is the foojay toolchain resolver really tied/coupled with the gradle version? I couldn't find a mapping on their github. Regardless, I've tried both 0.5 and 0.7 to no success.

#### Versions / Details

`java --version`

```
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

`gradlew -- version`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-06-30 18:02:30 UTC
Revision:     5f4a070a62a31a17438ac998c2b849f4f6892877

Kotlin:       1.8.20
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.9 (Eclipse Adoptium 17.0.9+9)
OS:           Windows Server 2022 10.0 amd64
```